# Hints About Exercise 6.31 of EOPL3

Tags: programming-languages, interpreter, continuation-passing

I am reading [EOPL 3rd edition](http://www.eopl3.com/). Now I am stuck on exercise 6.31.

> **Exercise 6.31** Write a translator that takes the output of `cps-of-program` and
>   produces an equivalent program in which all the continuations are represented
>   by data structures, as in chapter 5. Represent data structures like those
>   constructed using `define-datatype` as lists. Since our language does not have
>   symbols, you can use an integer tag in the car position to distinguish the
>   variants of a data type.

I can't solve this one because I have no idea what the result program should
look like. For example, consider the program below:

```lisp
+(1, (f x), (g y))
```

After CPS we got the following program:

```lisp
(f x
   (proc (v1)
      (g y
         (proc (v2)
            (proc (v0) v0)
             +(1, v1, v2)))))
```

Here, the procedure in the position `K` as in `(f x K)` is the continuation. The
question is I have a very vague view on how the data structure version of `K`
looks like. One possibility is:

```lisp
(f x
   (call-cont g
              (y)
              (sum-cont 1
                        ?
                        (end-cont))))
```

However, because simple expressions are regarded as a whole, I don't know how to
convert `+(1, v1, v2)` to something like `sum-cont1`, `sum-cont2` as in
chapter 5. As a result, I can only use a question mark `?` in the data structure
representation. Without knowing how the equivalent program looks like, it is
impossible to solve this exercise for me. Could anyone please give some hints?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistaken in your CPS transformation, check page 216 which shows that `(cps-of-exp <<+((f x), 33, (g y))>> K)` ends up being

```
(f x
   proc (v1)
      (g y
         proc (v2)
            (K +(v1, 33, v2))))
```

so

`+(1, (f x), (g y))`

would get transformed to

```
(f x
   proc (v1)
      (g y
         proc (v2)
            (K +(1, v1, v2))))
```

You had added `(proc (v0) v0)` and missed out `K`.

---

The task of turning it into data structures is to apply defunctionalization. Each procedure is replaced by a data structure. Look back to chapter 5 section 3 page 163 which covers an example of this. The apply-cont function turns the data structures back into continuation procedures.

In our case we want data structures to represent calling the functions f and g and one to represent calling the plus function with one value and 2 arguments. For the plus continuation we will require 2 values. The g continuation will put 2 values into its continuation and the f continuation will put one value into its continuation.

So like this:

`(f-cont x (g-cont y (plus-ynn-cont 1 (exit-cont))))`

with

```
(apply-cont (f-cont x k))
 = (apply-cont k (f x))

(apply-cont (g-cont y k) val)
 = (apply-cont k (g y) val)

(apply-cont (plus-ynn z k) val1 val2)
 = (apply-cont k (+ z val1 val2))

(apply-cont (exit-cont) val)
 = (print val)
```

Comment: First, I don't think it is a mistake in my transform. Becuase what appears as a continuation depends on what is passed. I used a CPSed function as continuation in the example, as in figure 6.12, page 224. Maybe I should write something like `(cps-of-exp <<+(1, (f x), (g y))>> <<proc (v0) v0>>)`, although this is inaccurate too. But thank you **soooo** much for your help! I now know what mistake I made: I regard `(f x K)` and `K` as two different things. In contrast, if I need to complete the translation, the CPSed result should be regarded as a whole. Thanks again!